# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [/userProfile.jsp] at line [20]

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

in my userprofile.jsp i have

```
<%@ page import="com.example.demo2.User" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<%
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("loginuser");
    if(user == null){
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }
%>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <title>User Profile</title>

</head>
<body>
<center>
    Welcome, <%= user.getFirstName()%> <%= user.getSurname()%>
    <form action="UpdateServlet" method="post">
        <br><input type="text" placeholder="Username/Email" name="email" ></br>
        <br><input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="passOne" ></br>
<%--        <br><input type="password" placeholder="Repeat password" name="passRepeat" ></br>--%>
        <br><input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="firstName"></br>
        <br><input type="text" placeholder="Surname" name="surname"></br>
        <br><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your age" name="age" ></br>
        <br><input type="text" placeholder="profession" name="profession" ></br>

        <button>Update</button>
    </form>
    <form action="LogoutServlet" method="post"><button>Logout</button></form>


</center>



</body></html>
```

i want to redirect page to index.jsp if user is null. How can i achieve this?
i tried `user.equals(null)`

Second Error i get

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.example.demo2.User.getFirstName()" because "user" is null**

Comment: If `user` is null then `user.equals(null)` will throw a `NullPointerException`. Try `user == null` instead.

Comment: Which I actually see now that you have in your code.

Comment: Is the redirect even working? I would suggest that you have some kind of processor before the jsp page (like a servlet) where you determine which jsp page to forward the request to.